# Looking for Angular Directive which enables model encapsulation

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have a template like this:

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Description:</span><span>{{YPOBatch.YarnPOBatch.YarnType.YarnTypeDesc}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>ID:</span><span>{{YPOBatch.YarnPOBatch.YarnType.YarnTypeID}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For purposes of writing clearer, easier to read and maintain code I want to be able to write something like:

```
    <div ng-directive-that-I-am-at-a-loss-for="YPOBatch.YarnPOBatch.YarnType">
        <div>
            <span>Description:</span><span>{{YarnTypeDesc}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>ID:</span><span>{{YarnTypeID}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so that both code blocks will be equivalent. Is there an angular out of the box directive that can do what I want?

Comment: If this is for a collection, check out ng-repeat

Comment: @MikeP: It is not a collection but your comment gave me an idea: `ng-repeat="yarnType in [YPOBatch.YarnPOBatch.YarnType]"`actually works. But it feels so hackish I am queasy about using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, on the surface this might seem like a neat idea... but in reality I'm not sure it's a good idea.

### Method 1. The Fancy Directive that is probably a bad idea

In order to do this, you'll need to create a new Scope and $compile it into the transcluded view. In other words, you take the guts of the element your directive is on, you clone it, you create a new child Scope, you update it to have the values from the property you specify, then you bind that new child scope to the cloned elements which are then appended to your element. You also then assign original property to be the newly created scope. Clear as mud? Heh.

**EDIT: I've eliminated the two-way binding problem**

**EDIT: ...and simplified it a lot**

It's still a little crazy though, because now your original $scope.property becomes a scope of it's own. But it works.

Anyhow, [here's a plunk of how you could do i](http://plnkr.co/edit/mnYzef4dRB9OUQsLHerm?p=preview)t, and some code... **I don't recommend using this or even trying it though**.

```js
app.directive('notSureWhyYoudWantThis', function($parse) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // get the property getter/setter
      var property = $parse(attrs.notSureWhyYoudWantThis);

      // get the value from the scope (inherited from parent)
      var base = property(scope);

      // extend the child scope with whatever is in the base property.
      angular.extend(scope, base);

      // now set the property on the parent scope to be the child scope,
      // so it updates both ways.
      property.assign(scope.$parent, scope);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div not-sure-why-youd-want-this="YPOBatch.YarnPOBatch.YarnType">
    <div>
        <span>Description:</span><span>{{YarnTypeDesc}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>ID:</span><span>{{YarnTypeYarnTypeID}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## Method 2. Best Idea: Scrub your data into a proper model, Mr. MVC-Programmer-Guy!

So the best idea here is the least sexy, you take that ugly data you got from your data source (AJAX, LocalStorage, whatever) and you actually groom it into a model that best represents your view/display logic. Then you put that model in a property on the $scope. Then end.

This is really what you're *supposed* to be doing in MVC, particularly if you're at all Domain Driven, but it's just not attractive for some people because of the extra work incurred, and sometimes there's a desire to be able to directly submit data front to back in a singular form.

```js
var ypoBatch= myService.getSomeDataFromSomething();

$scope.yarnType = {
   id: ypoBatch.YarnPOBatch.YarnTypeYarnTypeID,
   description:  ypoBatch.YarnPOBatch.YarnTypeDesc
};
```

then in your view:

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <span>Description:</span> <span>{{yarnType.description}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>ID:</span> <span>{{yarnType.id}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Boring: Yes.

Better: Probably.

How you do the above is going to be situational, obviously. But that's the idea. And now you have many ways to skin this cat. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I've tried ng-init, but it does not seem to work. Could that be because the data arrives asynchronously after the page is loaded and angular has already bound the data?

Comment: By the way, I agree that the third approach is the best way to go. But the model I receive from my datasource is already stripped down to the bones so that there are no properties which are not displayed in the view. Having said that, it is organized according to a rather deep hierarchical conception of the nature of "real world" data. In effect I would be flattening the property tree. I have some reservations about that which I will later try to address through an edit to the OP because I am running out of comment space.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu: About ng-init ... yes it's probably due to asynchronicity.

Comment: I've updated my directive example so that it will now update the original scope property. I still don't know if I'd recommend that route though.

Comment: Also removing the second method I recommended as it's probably only going to work in a few select cases.

Comment: .. and further simplified.

Comment: Upvoted for Method 2. Directive is an overkill for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I don't believe there is anything like this. You could try something like this

```
app.directive('expandModel', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      angular.extend(scope, scope.$eval(attrs.expandModel));
    }
  }
});
```

This will create a new scope for the directive that still prototypically inherits from its parent, while copying over all model values for the property path you specified.

Alternatively if you expect the model value to change, use scope.$watch instead of scope.$eval.

Plunker is acting up right now otherwise I'd have a plunk for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the you are shooting for the wrong level of abstraction.  If you need a directive to show information about yarn, you can wrap the entire presentation into a reusable chunk.

```
module.directive('yarnDisplay', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            yarn: '=' //the parent scope will manage finding the yarn
        },
            template: '<div><div><span>Description:</span><span>{{yarn.YarnTypeDesc}}</span></div><div><span>ID:</span><span>{{yarn.YarnTypeYarnTypeID}}</span></div></div>',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, controller) {

            }
}]);
```

with that directive, anytime you need to display info about yarn you include the following HTML:

```
<yarn-display yarn='YPOBatch.YarnPOBatch' />
```